# Shared memory corrupting data

Tags: c, shared-memory

I'm trying to write a program that uses counting semaphores, a mutex, and two threads. One thread is a producer that writes items to shared memory. Each item has a sequence number, timestamp, checksum, and some data. The consumer thread copies the original checksum from an item then calculates its own checksum from the item's data and compares the two to make sure the data wasn't corrupted.

My program runs, however, it reports incorrect checksums far more than correct checksums. I did some print statements to see what was going on, and it looks like the item's data is changing between writing to shared memory and reading from it. The item's stored checksum is also changing, and I have no idea what is causing this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>

typedef struct{
  int seqNo;
  uint16_t checksum;
  uint32_t timeStamp;
  uint8_t data[22];

}Item;
char* shm_name = "buffer";
int shm_fd;
uint8_t  *shm_ptr;
pthread_t producers;
pthread_t consumers;
pthread_mutex_t mutex;
sem_t *empty, *full;
int shmSize;
int in = 0;
int out = 0;


//method for initializing shared memory
void CreateSharedMemory(){


  shm_fd = shm_open(shm_name, O_CREAT | O_RDWR, 0644);
  if (shm_fd == -1) {
      fprintf(stderr, "Error unable to create shared memory, '%s, errno = %d (%s)\n", shm_name,
              errno, strerror(errno));
      return -1;
  }

  /* configure the size of the shared memory segment */
  if (ftruncate(shm_fd, shmSize) == -1) {
       fprintf(stderr, "Error configure create shared memory, '%s, errno = %d (%s)\n", shm_name,
              errno, strerror(errno));
       shm_unlink(shm_name);
       return -1;
  }

  printf("shared memory create success, shm_fd = %d\n", shm_fd);
}

uint16_t checksum(char *addr, uint32_t count)
{
    register uint32_t sum = 0;

    uint16_t *buf = (uint16_t *) addr;

    // Main summing loop
    while(count > 1)
    {
        sum = sum + *(buf)++;
        count = count - 2;
    }

    // Add left-over byte, if any
    if (count > 0)
        sum = sum + *addr;

    // Fold 32-bit sum to 16 bits
    while (sum>>16)
        sum = (sum & 0xFFFF) + (sum >> 16);

    return(~sum);

}


Item CreateItem(){
  Item item;
  uint16_t cksum;
  int j = 0;
  time_t seconds;
  seconds = time(NULL);


  item.seqNo = j;
  item.timeStamp = seconds; //FIX this
  for(int i = 0; i < 22; ++i){
    item.data[i] = rand() % 256;
  }
  cksum = checksum(&item.data[0], shmSize-2);

  item.checksum = cksum;

  ++j;
  return item;
}

void* producer() {

  shm_fd = shm_open(shm_name, O_RDWR, 0644);
  shm_ptr = (uint8_t *)mmap(0, 32, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);

    while(1) {
        Item tempItem = CreateItem();
        tempItem.seqNo = in;
   

        sem_wait(empty);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

        while (((in + 1)%shmSize) == out)
            ; // waiting

        if(in < shmSize) {
            //&shm_ptr[counter] = item;
\
            memcpy(&shm_ptr[in], &tempItem, 32);
            printf("%d\n", tempItem.seqNo);
 
            in = (in + 1) % shmSize;
            printf("Producer: %x\n", tempItem.checksum);


        }

        sleep(1);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        sem_post(full);
    }
}

void* consumer() {
    uint16_t cksum1, cksum2;
    shm_fd = shm_open(shm_name, O_RDWR, 0644);
    shm_ptr = (uint8_t *)mmap(0, shmSize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, shm_fd, 0);
    while(1) {
        sem_wait(full);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

        while (in == out)
            ; // waiting

        if(out > 0) {
            Item tempItem;
            memcpy(&tempItem, &shm_ptr[out], 32);

            cksum1 = tempItem.checksum;
            cksum2 = checksum(&tempItem.data[0], shmSize-2);
            if (cksum1 != cksum2) {
               printf("Checksum mismatch: expected %02x, received %02x \n", cksum2, cksum1);
  
            }
            else{
              printf("removed from shm\n");
            }
            //printf("Checksums match !!! \n");
            out = (out + 1)%shmSize;



        }

        sleep(1);

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
        sem_post(empty);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){

  sem_unlink(&empty);
  sem_unlink(&full);
  shm_unlink(shm_name);


  shmSize = atoi(argv[1]);
  out = shmSize;
  if(shmSize < 0){
    printf("Error: Size of buffer cannot be negative. ");
    return -1;
  }


  pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
  empty = sem_open("/empty", O_CREAT, 0644, shmSize);
  full = sem_open("/full", O_CREAT, 0644, 0);

  CreateSharedMemory();



  pthread_create(&producers, NULL, producer, NULL);
  pthread_create(&consumers, NULL, consumer, NULL);

  pthread_exit(NULL);
```

Comment: Sounds like your synchronization efforts failed. Additionally, using global variables like this is asking for trouble if you're using threads.

Comment: You're holding the lock open in the consumer while sleeping. That seems rude, to say the least. When using locks, get in and out as quickly as possible. Delays lead to deadlocks.

Comment: `while (in == out)` seems like it urgently needs the atomic treatment.

Comment: I'd suggest using some kind of message passing system to coordinate between threads, if not, at the absolute least, a condition variable to signal when it's time to read.